# Custom reverse proxy

Tags: wordpress, reverse-proxy

We have a Webapplication which is hosted on server A.
One of our customers has a Wordpress instance hosted on server B.
We can't host the Wordpress instance on server A.

We could use seperate subdomains but this would be bad for SEO.

We are thinking about building a 'reverse proxy':

If a request is directed to Webapplication A it should reply the request.
But is a request is done on a specific directory the application should get te content from the corresponding url on the WordPress instance and reply it to the client. We have a working proof of concept of this. All heavy content like css, js and images is requeste by the client directly.

However, we are concerned about:
1) Logins in WordPress
2) Forms posted

Can this be done or should we just forget about it...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **nginx** as proxy for some uri or methods/etc for server B and proxying them to server A.

[proxy_pass on nginx.org](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Comment: We have tried it and it works perfectly. We did set up a Azure Virtual Machine, so it was quick to try. We'll have to make some changes to the (overlapping) directory structure but that is not to hard. Thanks!